# JWT authentication not working when spring boot app deployed to kubernetes cluster with nginix controller

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, jwt, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a Spring boot app with end point POST /login which validates the credentials and returns the JWT in the response header. There is another endpoint /api/cars/listing which requires Authorization header with valid JWT. This app is deployed to a Kubernetes cluster with 3 nodes. After that I have installed ngnix ingress controller for L7 routing within the cluster and added the ingress resource.

Followed this tutorial - https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke.

When I use the JWT generated from POST /login and use it for GET /api/cars/listings I am getting 403 error in the response.  Is there anything that I need to configure in the Nginx ingress controller for routing the request to the same node based on the request IP?

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
 rules:
 - http:
    paths:
     - path: /jwt(/|$)(.*)
       backend:
        serviceName: jwt-app-service
        servicePort: 80
```

POST /jwt/login

GET /jwt/api/cars/listings

Comment: I guess something is broken with your application because NGINX performs barely proxy pass to your backend service: please share more details or logs of your JWT-based application

Comment: @prometherion Yeah you are right. The issue looks like is in the application code itself. JWT signature does not match the locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
 at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:383) ~[jjwt-impl-0.10.5.jar:?]

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the kubectl logs, found the issue was related to JWT secret key generation. Everytime the spring boot app restarted the secret key got dynamically generated.

I was using `Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512);` in the Spring config file as below. This could be configured as deployment env variable or in some other secured way.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private final JwtTokenService jwtTokenService;

  private AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  public SecurityConfig(AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService) {
    this.jwtTokenService = jwtTokenService();
    this.appUserDetailsService = appUserDetailsService;
  }

  public SecurityConfig() {
    this.jwtTokenService = jwtTokenService();
  }

  private Key base64EncodedSecretKey() {
    return Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512);
  }


  private JwtTokenService jwtTokenService() {
    return new JwtTokenService(base64EncodedSecretKey());
  }


  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(this.appUserDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/greetings").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new LoginFilter("/login", this.jwtTokenService, authenticationManager()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(this.jwtTokenService, "/api/**"), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);


  }
}
```